# Check for duplicate word in comma-separated string in bash

Tags: bash, macos, csv

I need to check that a variable does not contain a duplicate entry in a comma-separated string.

For example, inside of `$animals`, if I have:

```
,dog,cat,bird,goat,fish,
```

That would be considered valid since every word is unique.

The string:

```
,dog,cat,dog,bird,fish,
```

would be invalid since `dog` is entered twice.

```
,dog,cat,dogs,bird,fish,
```

Would be valid since there is only one instance of `dog` (`dogs` is there but allowed since it's not the same exact word)

The string:

```
,dog,cat,DOG,bird,fish
```

Would also be invalid since `dog` is the same as `DOG` only in uppercase.

Is there any way I can do this? I would put some code I've tried but I don't know what to use to even experiment.

Using bash 3.2.57(1)-release on 10.11.6 El Capitan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case sensitive:**

```
echo ",dog,cat,dog,bird,fish," | tr ',' '\n' | grep -v '^$' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1,1nr
```

**Case insensitive**:

```
echo ",dog,DOG,cat,dog,bird,fish," | tr ',' '\n' | grep -v '^$' | sort -rf | uniq -ci | sort -k 1,1nr
```

Perform a reverse sort (`-r`) and do it case insensitive to get the lower-case letters after upper ones. Then `uniq` them with `-i`. (You might have to ensure the defined collation `LC_COLLATE` and maybe locales like `LANG` and `LC_ALL` aren't affecting `sort` behavior).

Then check if the number in the first row > 1

Comment: `Then check if the number in the first row > 1` could be done with simple `awk` scripts, like `awk '{ if ($1 > 1) print "Contains duplicates"; }'` maybe with `head -n1`. One could even `| grep -v ' *1 ' | wc -l` and compare the count with zero.

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely too! I could see this also being useful in an application where tallying duplicates and listing them out would be needed.

Comment: Additionally, if your version of `uniq` adds spaces to the beginning of the strings then piping it to `sed 's/^[\ ]*//'` will remove those spaces.

Comment: Checking for case sensitive duplicates can also be achieved using this if statement: `if echo ",dog,cat,dog,bird,fish," | tr ',' '\n' | grep -v '^$' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1,1nr | sed 's/^[\ ]*//' | grep -vq '^1\ '; then echo "Contains duplicates"; else echo "Contains no duplicates";fi`

Answer (score 2):

## Simple script-based solution

#### Usage

```sh
$ .\script.sh ,dog,dog,cat,
```

#### Actual Script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

num_duplicated() {
    echo $1 |
    tr ',' '\n' | # Split each items into its own line
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | # Convert everything to lowercase
    sort | # Sorts the lines (required for the call to `uniq`
    uniq -d | # Passing the `-d` flag to show only duplicated lines
    grep -v '^$' | # Passing `-v` on the pattern `^$` to remove empty lines
    wc -l # Count the number of duplicate lines
}

main() {
    num_duplicates=$(num_duplicated "$1") 
    if [[ $num_duplicates -eq '0' ]]
    then
        echo "No duplicates"
    else
        echo "Contains duplicate(s)"
    fi
}

main $1
```

Comment: @KamilCuk good catch on the `wc -l | # Count...`, I was tidying up on Stack Overflow editor without double checking. On your second point, I think perhaps we'll let OP clarify what he/she meant by `... Would also be invalid since dog is not the same as DOG.`

Comment: This worked quite well for me, thanks! Also like the breakdown of each command in the comments. And about the "invalid since dog is not the same as DOG" I made a mistake. I am not a native English speaker, I have a friend who translates German/English for me. I edited the question to fix the issue.

Comment: Also, doesn't `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:']` need to be `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`? I changed it in your question but if I'm incorrect feel free to change it back.